# How to get text from a class placeholder textbox

Tags: c#, selenium, element

I have been trying to read the text from a textbox which is a class place holder as you can see below

UPDATE:

```
 <div id="annotationHistoryDataTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">

  <label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria- 
  controls="annotationHistoryDataTable">

 </label></div>
```

I am using the below code to get the text but i am getting a null value. This usually gets all the text but is not working for this kind of text box.

```
 var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("annotationHistoryDataTable")).Text;
```

Tried with By.LinkText too but still not working.

Here is the example of the textbox i want to read

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks - Also an url, would help to get more context.

Comment: @HedgeHog It's a page which is accessible for only the employees working in my team via vpn hence could not share any link.

Comment: var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//input[@aria-controls='annotationHistoryDataTable']")).Text; or with .getAttribute("whateverholdsthevalue") try something like this.

Comment: @jonathan PETIT approach was the same too. But still it is not working. I am not sure why it is not working. Can we have an approach where we can get all the input values of a page and get their texts accordingly so that we can actually find the textbox name by the value given in the field? just an opinion

Comment: If you have entered some text in the `inputbox` and then wanted to verify that text then you need to wait for sometimes and then get the value using  `element.getAttribute("value")`

Comment: @KunduK I am really sorry if this sounds negative from my end that it is not working,but i did that and kept a timer.sleep(10000) but still cannot get the text.

Comment: Just tried using the CSS selector path as well "#relatedInvestigationSearchResult_filter > label > input[type=search]" which was extracted from the webpage ,still showing the same error

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq Which _text_ / _value_ are you trying to extract?

Comment: @DebanjanB annotationHistoryDataTable value. The value "test"

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq `annotationHistoryDataTable` is the value of _aria-controls_ attribute which I can help you to extract. But what is _value "test"_ as per your comment?

Comment: @DebanjanB in the picture that was attached in the question, the textbox contains the value "test". That value I want to extract

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq IMO, the element in the picture containing the value "10" and the HTML you provided are different elements.

Comment: @DebanjanB The value  i want is of the right control which is a text box not the left one which a combo box

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq Is `test` the default text within the `<input>` when you access the webpage afresh or you have written the text within?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have written the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens

1. You try to get that `input` by `driver.FindElement(By.TagName("annotationHistoryDataTable")).Text;`
2. Ask yourself: Is there a TagName `annotationHistoryDataTable`?

### So how to select this `input`?

1. It is an `input` and it has an `aria-controls`, use this in your `xpath`:

   ```
   driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//input[@aria-controls='annotationHistoryDataTable']"))
   ```
2. The `text` is not stored between the `<input>` it is stored in the `value` attribute, so you should access it like:

   ```
   .GetAttribute("value")
   ```

**Example**

It is in python, but should show you what I mean.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = """
  <label>
   Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="annotationHistoryDataTable"> 
 </label>
"""

browser.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-controls='annotationHistoryDataTable']").get_attribute("value")
browser.close()
```

Comment: Yes. I totally agree with your way @Hedgehog and tried what you said and still getting the error. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[aria-controls="annotationHistoryDataTable" and type = "search"]"}
Now I am getting a doubt whether this is a readable textbox or not? 
Can we have an approach where we can get all the input values of a page and get their texts accordingly so that we can actually find the textbox name by the value given in the field?

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq : Your `xpath` is still incorrect. It should be  `"//input[@aria-controls='annotationHistoryDataTable']"` as @HedgeHog mentioned his post. I can see you have missed `@` before attributename in your xpath.

Comment: Actually in the comment box not more than two characters "@" where allowed so just removed that. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq: Is `test` a placeholder or an typed one text??? If it is a placeholder than use `.GetAttribute("placeholder")` then may your example of the html is not correct.

Comment: it is a place holder, I did try with the placeholder attitude as well still no success, I have updated the html code with some more content. Please check for reference

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq: Answering your question, if this is the correct element, you can select the `text` of its parent that should be `Search:` like that `driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//input[@aria-controls='annotationHistoryDataTable']")).FindElement(By.XPATH("..")).Text`

Comment: @HedheHog Still not working. Can this Xpath be used to write a code?
//*[@id="relatedInvestigationSearchResult_filter"]/label/input

I cannot find this when used in selenium but got the xpath from the webpage

Comment: @GarnimittaIshaq as figured out in the comments of `PDHide` it would only work if you switch to the `iframe` before. Any way I would close this answer and you should open a new one concerning the writing code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
 var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("annotationHistoryDataTable")).get_attribute("innerText");
```

Comment: Still getting the error that the handle cannot be found.
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"annotationHistoryDataTable"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)'

Answer (score 1):

## Your locator looks incorrect:

```
 var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("annotationHistoryDataTable")).Text;
```

## There is no tag with that name ,use below locator instead

```
 var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//input[@aria-controls=\"annotationHistoryDataTable\" and @type = \"search\"]"));
```

Now try ;

```
 theseElements.text
 theseElements.getAttribute('value')
```

### Update:

so as elements are inside iframe you need to switch to it first

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("iframexpath")));
var theseElements = driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//input[@aria-controls=\"annotationHistoryDataTable\" and @type = \"search\"]"));
theseElements.getAttribute('value') //print this
```

If you want to interact with elements outside the iframe after this , then you have to switch outside of iframe;

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); // just add this line after you are done with interacting with iframe elements
```

Comment: Not working.
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/label/input
//*[@id="annotationHistoryDataTable_filter"]/label/input

these are the full x path and the xpath but still the textbox is not accessible inspite of being directly mentioning the path. Not sure what is wrong with that placeholder

Comment: are you getting element not found ?

Comment: Yes, the element is not found

Comment: See whether element is inside iframe

Comment: I guess it is. there are alot of Iframe keywords in them,
//*[@id="annotationHistoryDataTable_filter"]/label/input

this is the xpath of the element i want to extract, will this work?

Comment: if the lement is child of iframe then you find that parent iframe and then switch to it before you can interact with the children

Comment: Updated the answer